# how to query a clicked polygon in mapserver with PHP?

Tags: php, mapserver

everyone. Please allow me a brief introduction.

---

For instance: My mapserver use **CGI** mode. I have a shapefile named `'us_states.shp'`, there's a column `'state_name'` in it. If I've written a correct `'.map'` file and a `'.html'` template, I should get a specific name of a US state when I click a map image in the 'form' tag. Why can this happen? Because the '.html' template has a string: **[state_name]**.

---

Now, I make some changes:

1. the spatial data is in a **postgreSQL** database, and there's also a column named `'state_name'`;
2. I'm using **PHP** to show the query map.

Then, *how can I get the value of `'state_name'`? how to change the color of the clicked state?*

My progress rate:

- a. I can show the original map image from the '.map' file using postgreSQL, and also show the names of all states in the image;
- b. a simple `'QUERYMAP'` paragraph have already exist in the '.map' file;
- c. I added these codes to my '.php' file:

> $point->setXY($img_x, $img_y);
>
> $map->queryByPoint($point, 'MS_SINGLE', -1);
>
> $image=$map->drawQuery();

However, *first*, the coordinates of the image aren't the ones of the database, as well as the coordinates in the database aren't latitudes or longitudes either! Need I transform them? *Second*, the method `'queryByPoint'` couldn't get the state name, Need I use `'queryByAttributes'`? How to use it?

I don't know... I really don't know... I need your help, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my question, even though it's not solved perfectly.

---

I have two purposes:

1. change the color clicked;
2. get the name of the state.

Actually, I don't need to solve all problems by MapServer. the first task depends on `Mapserver`, the second depends on `postgreSQL` and `PHP`.

---

The first task:

Change the old code:

```
$point->setXY($img_x, $img_y);
$map->queryByPoint($point, 'MS_SINGLE', -1);
$image=$map->drawQuery();
```

To the new code:

```
$point->setXY($map_x, $map_y);
$map->queryByPoint($point, 'MS_SINGLE', -1);
$image=$map->drawQuery();
```

The color of state clicked will be changed. I just change **$img_x** to **$map_x**, **$img_y** to **$map_y**. But how to get the correct coordinates of the point? Only two Variable are required: *the extent of the map*, *the size of the image*. When you get them, conversion from image point to map coordinate is easy. I am afraid I will not repeat them.

---

The second task:

If you got the coordinate of the map, you will query the state from postgresql database easily.
Here is the query code with PHP:

```
$query = "select state_name from country where within(GeomFromText('Point($map_x $map_y)', 4269), the_geom)";
$result = pg_query($query);
if($result) {
  list($state) = pg_fetch_row($result);
}
```

---

As you can see, you do not need the mapserver to complete everything.

By the way, I got the inspiration from a book, "*Beginning MapServer: Open Source GIS Development*", written by Bill Kropla. It's a nice book and teach me a lot!